# Formatting a time datepicker and displaying the time in a textfield

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am trying to display the time in the datePicker in a textfield. I have gotten this far

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 88, 97, 30)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate //what do I put here to put the datepicker time in the textfield]];
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
datePicker.minuteInterval = 5;
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

[textField setInputView:datePicker];
```

EDIT

I dont have anything in the value did change but here it is

```
-(void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{


}
```

Comment: can you show your `datePickerValueChanged` method.

Comment: Its updated to in the question now

Answer (score 4):

**.h File**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *textField;
    UIDatePicker *dpDatePicker;
}

@end
```

**.m File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 88, 250, 30)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    dpDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    dpDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [dpDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    dpDatePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dpDatePicker.minuteInterval = 5;

    [textField setInputView:dpDatePicker];
}
```

**Setting up the date picker value changed method to display the user selected value.**

```
- (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dpDatePicker.date];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSDateFormatter`'s `stringFromDate:` method like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; //Choose the appropriate style for your case
textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

You can find the documentation for `NSDateFormatter` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: i tried this and the textfield doesnt change. Is there a way I need to update the textfield?

Comment: Put the above code in your `datePickerValueChanged:` method. You'll want to make your `textField` a property.